# Can I transfer files to/from an iPhone over wifi without knowing IP addresses?

Tags: wifi, iphone, kde-connect

I am a new iPhone owner.

Previously, I installed [KDE Connect](https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect) on both my GNU/Linux laptop and Android device. This allowed me to pair the devices on my local network without knowing their local IP addresses, and transfer files between them without a cable.

It appears that there is no Connect-compatible client on the Apple App Store (see footnote 1). I have found instructions for [pairing and transferring files to/from an iPhone with a cable](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-iphone-6.html). I don't want to rely on an internet connection.

How can I:

- pair a GNU/Linux system with an iPhone on a local wifi network
- without knowing their respective IP addresses
- and then transfer files between them?

Installing packages/apps on either device is acceptable, but the apps must be libre licensed (even on the Apple App Store).

---

Footnote 1:

> There was some development of a KDE Connect client app for iOS in 2014... but due to our experience and various technical and organizational factors it's unlikely that we will have official iOS support anytime soon. https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect#Installation

Comment: Have you found a way to do it, when you know the IP address?

Comment: when I cannot use a usb connection, I use `FE File Explorer` (https://www.skyjos.com/fileexplorer/)  on the phone and `samba` on the laptop

Comment: If you don't find a good suggestion here, perhaps try restructuring your question into a software suggestion, here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/